# Long elif chains vs dictionary with exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am a novice to python and I have read a lot of tutorials on how to properly code. One thing that keep popping up is to never write the same line of code multiple times. I am unsure if long elif arguments count for that, but to me it just looks like bad code.

for exaple:

```
class answers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'hello world'

    def knight(self):
        print('Neee!')
    def bunny(self):
        print('Rawwww!')
    def pesant(self):
        print('Witch!')
    def dingo(self):
        print('Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!')
foo = answers()    
egg = input("Sounds:")

if egg == "knight":
    foo.knight()
elif egg == 'bunny':
    foo.bunny()
elif egg == 'pesant':
    foo.pesant()
elif egg == 'dingo':
    foo.dingo()
else:
    print("I don't know?")
```

That works but I think the following code is looks cleaner.

```
class answers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'hello world'

    def knight(self):
        print('Neee!')
    def bunny(self):
        print('Rawwww!')
    def pesant(self):
        print('Witch!')
    def dingo(self):
        print('Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!')

foo = answers()
responce = {'knight': 'foo.knight()', 'bunny': 'foo.bunny()', 'pesant': 'foo.pesant()', 'dingo': 'foo.dingo()'}

while True:
    try:
        egg = input('sounds:')
        exec(responce[egg])
    except KeyError:
        print("I don't know")
```

Both lines of code do the same thing, does it really matter which I use or is one better then the other?

side note, I know that exec() should not normally be used but I could not find another way to assign a function to a string.

Comment: use `'knight': foo.knight,` (function name without `""` and `()`) and then run it without `exec()` like this `responce[egg]()`  (with `()` )

Comment: but I would rather use dictionary with `"knight": "Neee!"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign function name to variable if you skip `()` and arguments

```
responce = {
    'knight': foo.knight,
    'bunny': foo.bunny,
    'pesant': foo.pesant,
    'dingo': foo.dingo,
}
```

And then you can run it using `()` (with expected arguments)

```
responce[egg]()

#responce[egg](arg1, arg2, ...) # if function require arguments
```

Full code

```
class Answers(object): # CamelCase name for class - see PEP8 document

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'hello world'

    def knight(self):
        print('Neee!')

    def bunny(self):
        print('Rawwww!')

    def pesant(self):
        print('Witch!')

    def dingo(self):
        print('Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!')

foo = Answers()

responce = {
    'knight': foo.knight,
    'bunny': foo.bunny,
    'pesant': foo.pesant,
    'dingo': foo.dingo,
}

while True:
    try:
        egg = input('sounds:')
        responce[egg]() # call function
    except KeyError:
        print("I don't know")
```

---

**BTW:** This way you can even use function name as argument for another function.

It is use in Tkinter to assign function to Button

```
Button( ..., text="knight", command=foo.knight)
```

or to assign function to event

```
bind('<Button-1>', foo.knight)
```

---

If you need to assign function with arguments then you can use `lambda` function.

Version for Python3:

```
responce = {
    'knight': lambda:print('Neee!'),
    'bunny': lambda:print('Rawwww!'),
    'pesant': lambda:print('Witch!'),
    'dingo': lambda:print('Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!'),
}
```

Version for Python2:

`print` in Python2 is not a function so `lambda` will not work with `print` - so you have to create function.

```
def show(text):
    print text

responce = {
    'knight': lambda:show('Neee!'),
    'bunny': lambda:show('Rawwww!'),
    'pesant': lambda:show('Witch!'),
    'dingo': lambda:show('Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!'),
}
```

---

**EDIT:** But I would do this without functions in dictionary :)

```
# --- classes ---

class Answers(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # TODO: read it from file CSV or JSON
        #
        # import json 
        #
        # with open("data.json") as f: 
        #     self.data = json.load(f)

        self.data = {
            'knight': 'Neee!',
            'bunny': 'Rawwww!',
            'pesant': 'Witch!',
            'dingo': 'Bad, wicked, naughty Zoot!',
        }

    def response(self, text):
        try:
            return self.data[text]
        except KeyError:
            return "I don't know"

# --- functions ---

  # empty

# --- main ---

foo = Answers()

while True:

    egg = input('sounds: ').lower()

    if egg == 'exit':
        break

    print(foo.response(egg))

# ---

print("Good Bye!")
```

Comment: Thank you for helping get rid of the exec(), with the updated code does it really matter if I use the dictionary vs the elif chain?

Comment: as for me it doesn't matter. Most people prefer `if/else`. But most people would do this code in different way - using one function `foo.show(text)` and dictionary with elements like `"knight": "Neee!"` because this dictionary can be readed from file (.csv or .json) or from database.

Comment: see my version in answer :)

Answer (score 0):

furas' great comment already well covers the how, but as for the *why* to do it this way, there is a better reason than "it looks cleaner":

Function tables tend to have less code -- both in terms of what you write and in terms of what the compiler or interpreter generates -- than case/switch statements or long chains of if/elif/else statements.

They also run faster.

So your instinct about it "looking cleaner" is quite correct, and indeed this is the way to do things, not just in Python, but in any programming language.